# Oracle - Difference between AND (Case1 OR Case2 OR Case3)

Tags: oracle

Hello everyone I have a fairly simple question.

I was wondering what the difference between

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE A = 'xxx' 
   AND (B = 'xxx' OR C='xxx' OR D='xxx')
```

And this Query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE A = 'xxx' 
   AND B = 'xxx' 
    OR C='xxx' 
    OR D='xxx'
```

In the bottom query it will return 2 results and the top query it returns zero results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE A = 'xxx' AND (B = 'xxx' OR C='xxx' OR D='xxx')
```

is equivalent to this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE A = 'xxx' AND B = 'xxx' OR 
      A = 'xxx' AND C = 'xxx' OR
      A = 'xxx' AND D = 'xxx'
```

The logic you put in a WHERE clause follows rules for Boolean expressions.  Just like with an algebraic expression, there is an order operations.  Generally, the order is

1. NOT
2. AND
3. OR

Answer (score 3):

```
A = 'xxx' AND B = 'xxx' OR C='xxx' OR D='xxx'
```

is equivalent to

```
(A = 'xxx' AND B = 'xxx') OR (C='xxx') OR (D='xxx')
```

thanks to [operators precedence order](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions001.htm#i1034834)